# Removing Subversion link to copied repo

Tags: svn

I have a local working copy of a Subversion repository.  I copied this local copy to a new directory, but it is still linked to the Subversion repository.  How do I remove this link to make it a true offline copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the directory you must be having a hidden **.svn** folder. Delete that folder and the SVN link will be gone.

Comment: Also, if you are working with `SVN` client older than 1.7, `.svn` folder will be present in every folder of working copy. As of version 1.7, it is present in root folder only.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, `svn export` may be what you're after.